# How to make the following table in 'tables' package in r?

Tags: r, package

Here is the example data.

```
cases = rep(c('case','control'),20)
age = sample(20:60,40)
df = data.frame(cases,age)
library(tables)
tabular((cases+1)~(n=1)+age*mean,data=df)
```

Here I need to add a third column with p values of t.test for age between the cases and controls. How can I do that?

Comment: I think it would be easier to make a table using some other function that returns a data.frame/matrix or some other "almost atomic" R structure that can be easily handled.

Comment: `res <- aggregate(age ~ cases, FUN = mean, data = df);
res$n <- table(df$cases);
res <- rbind(res, data.frame(cases = "all", age = mean(res$age), n = sum(res$n)))` should get you started with an elegant data.frame.